# Image still available after I delete it from server and cleared browser cache

Tags: image, caching

I wanted to change the logo image on my website, and stumbled upon this weird behavior:

#### Situation 1:

I upload a new img under a new name (`mysite.com/new.jpg`). I visit that URL in incognito. I delete the img from the server and visit the URL again.

**Expected behavior:**
The img can't be found.

**What's actually happening:**
The img still loads in the browser. It's not in the cache of the browser, I double checked that. When a colleague (on the same LAN) visits the URL, the image still loads, even though this colleague has never visited that img URL before.

#### Situation 2:

I upload a new img under a new name (`mysite.com/new2.jpg`). I visit that URL in incognito. I delete the img from the server. **I switch to my mobile hotspot** and visit the URL again.

**Expected behavior:** the img can't be found.

**Actual behavior** = expected behavior.

#### Situation 3:

I upload a new img under a new name (`mysite.com/new3.jpg`). **I don't visit that URL**. I delete the img from the server and visit the URL.

**Expected behavior:** the img can't be found.

**Actual behavior** = expected behavior.

## Question:

How can situation 1 be explained? It happens for images (not only .jpg), but it does not happen for example for html files. Is it caching the image on the server for a certain IP address somehow? I recently moved to a dedicated server and I didn't configure this myself, but maybe it's enabled by default? How can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by Cloudflare's caching rules.
Thought I'd post it here, maybe it can help others debugging this quicker in the future.